# Chebyshev's Inequality and CLT

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems, chebyshev-function

I am very confused as to how to approach questions 2 and 3 and the example problems in my notes don't have this specific problem structure. Any help would be great, here is the question below:

> Suppose we want to estimate the pH of a mysterious liquid. Let the true
>   pH be 5. We take n readings and let Xi be the value returned by the ith reading. You should assume the
>   readings are independent and that $E[X_i] = 5$ and var$[X_i] = 2$. Let $Y = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + X_2 + \dotsb + X_n)$ be the average of these readings.
>
> 1. Find out the mean and variance of $Y$ .
> 2. How large does $n$ need to be such that $P(4.9 < Y < 5.1) ≥ 0.99$ using the Chebyshev’s inequality?
> 3. How large does n need to be such that $P(4.9 < Y < 5.1) ≥ 0.99$ using the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Have you managed to answer part 1?  Do you know anything about Chebyshev's inequality or the Central limit Theorem?

Comment: yes i think i managed to answer part one because it would be nσ^2 for variance and then it would nμ for the expected mean of Y. i have the formulas for both and i think i understand how they work and what they're used for